# How to speed up this code?

Tags: c#, bioinformatics

I got the following method which is used to read a txt file and return a dictionary. It takes ~7 mins to read a ~5MB file (67000 lines, 70 chars in each line).

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> FASTAFileReadIn(string file)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> seq = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Regex re;
    Match m;
    GroupCollection group;
    string currentName = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith(">"))
                {// Match Sequence
                    re = new Regex(@"^>(\S+)");
                    m = re.Match(line);
                    if (m.Success)
                    {
                        group = m.Groups;
                        if (!seq.ContainsKey(group[1].Value))
                        {
                            seq.Add(group[1].Value, string.Empty);
                            currentName = group[1].Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (Regex.Match(line.Trim(), @"\S+").Success &&
                            currentName != string.Empty)
                {
                    seq[currentName] += line.Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An IO exception has benn thrown!");
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    finally { }

    return seq;
}
```

Which part of the code is most time consuming and how to speed it up?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Comment: @Brian, thanks, that saves some time. :)

Comment: Don't create a new regular expression each time. Create it once, and use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag for some extra performance.

Comment: try to avoid regular expression they typically take more time

Comment: You're using strings and string concatenation a lot; look into using `StringBuilder` - it should help speed things up considerably in your case. You could rewrite your `Dictionary` to `Dictionary<string, StringBuilder>` as a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache and compile regular expressions, reorder conditionals, lessen number of trimmings, and such.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> FASTAFileReadIn(string file) {
    var seq = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Regex re = new Regex(@"^>(\S+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Regex nonWhitespace = new Regex(@"\S", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Match m;
    string currentName = string.Empty;

    try {
        foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(file)) {
            if(line[0] == '>') {
                m = re.Match(line);

                if(m.Success) {
                    if(!seq.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value)) {
                        seq.Add(m.Groups[1].Value, string.Empty);
                        currentName = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    }
                }
            } else if(currentName != string.Empty) {
                if(nonWhitespace.IsMatch(line)) {
                    seq[currentName] += line.Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("An IO exception has been thrown!");
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    return seq;
}
```

*However*, that's just a naïve optimization. Reading up on the FASTA format, I wrote this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ReadFasta(string filename) {
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>
    var current = new StringBuilder();
    string currentKey = null;

    foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(filename)) {
        if(line[0] == '>') {
            if(currentKey != null) {
                result.Add(currentKey, current.ToString());
                current.Clear();
            }

            int i = line.IndexOf(' ', 2);

            currentKey = i > -1 ? line.Substring(1, i - 1) : line.Substring(1);
        } else if(currentKey != null) {
            current.Append(line.TrimEnd());
        }
    }

    if(currentKey != null)
        result.Add(currentKey, current.ToString());

    return result;
}
```

Tell me if it works; it should be much faster.

Comment: Does `string line in File.ReadAllLines()` build an entire (array? list?) from the file in one go, or does it build each `line` on-demand?

Comment: @sarnold: Sorry, you're right. I meant `ReadLines()`, which creates an `IEnumerable<string>`. (Although if the file is only 5MB, it may be beneficial to read the whole thing to begin with...)

Comment: Yeah, five megs, it probably doesn't matter much one way or the other. But I've seen some _huge_ FASTA files before..

Comment: What happens if currentKey (identifier of the sequence) is followed by a tab instead of a space?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: It's treated as part of the identifier. From what I can glean from the Wikipedia article, a space and not a tab should always be used. Otherwise... `IndexOfAny` :)

Comment: Another tiny nitpick: `line.IndexOf(' ')` -> `line.IndexOf(' ', 1)` because you've already examined the first character.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Was just adding that :) Actually, it'll be `2` because it shouldn't be blank. I think not, at least... why is there no actual spec I can see somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

I hope the compiler would do this automatically, but the first thing I notice is you're re-compiling the regular expression on every matching line:

```
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith(">"))
                {// Match Sequence
                    re = new Regex(@"^>(\S+)");
```

Even better if you can remove the regular expressions completely; most languages provide a `split` function of some sort that often smokes regular expressions...

Comment: Agreed, 're' should be well-defined outside the loop.

Comment: I did statistics on this, the best way to do it is to make them static and using the `RegexOptions.Compiled`.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the reading speed substantially by using a [`BufferedStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx):

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    // Use the StreamReader
}
```

The `Regex` recompile @sarnold mentioned is probably your largest performance killer, though, if your processing time is ~5 minutes.

Comment: Hah, when I saw your answer, my first thought was, "hey, I'll bet that's where 90% of the slowdown is coming from".

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write it. Without more information (i.e how long the average dictionary entry is) I can't optimize the StingBuilder capacity. You could also follow Eric J.'s advice and add a `BufferedStream`. Ideally, you'd do away with `Regular Expressions` entirely if you want to crank out the performance, but they are a lot easier to write and manage, so I understand why you'd want to use them.

```
public static Dictionary<string, StringBuilder> FASTAFileReadIn(string file)
{
    var seq = new Dictionary<string, StringBuilder>();
    var regName = new Regex("^>(\\S+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var regAppend = new Regex("\\S+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    Match tempMatch = null;
    string currentName = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((tempMatch = regName.Match(line)).Success)
                {
                    if (!seq.ContainsKey(tempMatch.Groups[1].Value))
                    {
                        currentName = tempMatch.Groups[1].Value;
                        seq.Add(currentName, new StringBuilder());
                    }
                }
                else if ((tempMatch = regAppend.Match(line)).Success && currentName != string.Empty)
                {
                    seq[currentName].Append(tempMatch.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An IO exception has been thrown!");
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    return seq;
}
```

As you can see, I've slightly changed your dictionary to use the optimized `StringBuilder` class for appending values. I've also pre-compiled the regular expressions once and once only to ensure that you aren't redundantly recompiling the same regular expression over and over again. I've also extracted your "append" case to compile into a Regular Expression as well.

Let me know if this helps you out performance-wise.